# C++: Always-Throw function in conditional expression

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

Conditional expressions allow throw expressions as operands. I would like to have a conditional expression where one of the operands is an always-throw function, however it appears that this is not possible.

```
#include<exception>

[[ noreturn ]] void foo() {
    throw std::exception();
}

int main() {
    int a = true ? 1 : throw std::exception();
    int b = true ? 1 : foo(); // This will not compile
}
```

I've tried inlining foo as well, but it wouldn't compile either. The error is the same:

```
test.cc: In function 'int main()':
test.cc:9:18: error: third operand to the conditional operator is of type 'void', but the second operand is neither a throw-expression nor of type 'void'
 int b = true ? 1 : foo(); // This will not compile
```

Is there a way to achieve calling that function inside the expression? My use case is a transpiler from a language to C++ and that other language supports case expressions where if no case is hit in the expression, an exception is thrown. Case expressions I'm trying to support are similar to this:

http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputsyntax/caseQexpressions_reference.html

Comment: Compiler won't always know what's inside a function and that it'll always throw, but what it DOES know is that `foo` can't ever return a `bool`. The return type doesn't line up with anything acceptable, so there's not much point to the compiler looking any further.

Comment: @user4581301 Returning from a `[[noreturn]]` is UB, so the compiler does know it'll either throw or terminate in a weird way.

Comment: Alright. It does have knowledge, and that leaves us with checking whether or not the compiler is required to match more than the return type. Wonder where to go looking for that in the Standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the comma operator like so:

```
int a = true ? 1 : (throw std::exception(), 0);
int b = true ? 1 : (foo(), 0);
```

See it working on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:34,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:34,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:34,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:34,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include%3Cexception%3E%0A%0A%5B%5B+noreturn+%5D%5D+void+foo()+%7B%0A++++throw+std::exception()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+a+%3D+true+%3F+1+:+(throw+std::exception(),+0)%3B%0A++++int+b+%3D+true+%3F+1+:+(foo(),+0)%3B+//+This+will+not+compile%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.09539384028346,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:glm,ver:trunk)),options:%27-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.904606159716536,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:49.904606159716536,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Comment: Does it change anything in the first line?